# Yahoo email account was used to send spams

Tags: spam-prevention, yahoo-mail

My Yahoo email account was sending spam at about 6:40pm today. I immediately updated my password. I also checked "[Recent Login Activity](https://api.login.yahoo.com/login/history)", but all recorded locations and IP addresses from 4:47 PM yesterday till now are my own.

How was it possible for my account to send spam while the recorded login activities are normal?

---

Header of one spam sent and saved in my "Sent" folder:

```
From Tim Thu Jun 14 15:42:07 2012
X-YMail-OSG: ivy79oIVM1k8kPIPgi4nfJh2JPdWcnzc7If0UmOfBQtmnkB
 nEmfLnPHJ
Received: from [187.41.82.250] by web162602.mail.bf1.yahoo.com via HTTP; Thu, 14 Jun 2012 15:42:07 PDT
X-Mailer: YahooMailWebService/0.8.118.349524
Message-ID: <1339713727.16968.BPMail_high_noncarrier@web162602.mail.bf1.yahoo.com>
Date: Thu, 14 Jun 2012 15:42:07 -0700 (PDT)
From: Tim <tim@yahoo.com>
Subject: HI
To: bankofamerica@replies.em.bankofamerica.com
Bcc: xxx@hotmail.com, xxx@yahoo.com, 
    xxx@gmail.com, 
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Length: 71
```

---

Yahoo notice of failure to deliver the spam to some intended address:

```
Sorry, we were unable to deliver your message to the following address.

<bankofamerica@replies.em.bankofamerica.com>:
Remote host said: 550 5.1.1 <bankofamerica@replies.em.bankofamerica.com> User unknown; rejecting [RCPT_TO]

--- Below this line is a copy of the message.

Received: from [98.139.212.148] by nm21.bullet.mail.bf1.yahoo.com with NNFMP; 14 Jun 2012 22:42:08 -0000
Received: from [98.139.212.214] by tm5.bullet.mail.bf1.yahoo.com with NNFMP; 14 Jun 2012 22:42:08 -0000
Received: from [127.0.0.1] by omp1023.mail.bf1.yahoo.com with NNFMP; 14 Jun 2012 22:42:08 -0000
X-Yahoo-Newman-Property: ymail-3
X-Yahoo-Newman-Id: 395299.5507.bm@omp1023.mail.bf1.yahoo.com
Received: (qmail 91992 invoked by uid 60001); 14 Jun 2012 22:42:08 -0000
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=yahoo.com; s=s1024; t=1339713728; bh=3k5IzdOBwo7Jx0VjjcU11ALbzymfvrJ2SheLqHngG7s=; h=X-YMail-OSG:Received:X-Mailer:Message-ID:Date:From:Subject:To:MIME-Version:Content-Type; b=mk5ksTksAaA1u+2GJaaQoJaClM5AQeOmUn4A9e3xYyJVpER/mKvPB6e5NJlZ2WG1zhOvnrMUHGgqwxMMa7lf3K9tHzGxhbLddTxfM0udgCC2Ws4d7ebgACo2lT/92A9qGxxPIXQCSAEiK8/C7P5rQ6ZAOGOv5xMHuSMY3lUzs9Y=
DomainKey-Signature:a=rsa-sha1; q=dns; c=nofws;
  s=s1024; d=yahoo.com;
  h=X-YMail-OSG:Received:X-Mailer:Message-ID:Date:From:Subject:To:MIME-Version:Content-Type;
  b=enSetbkOfQmTtzS221NeSMw+dVAbV6y4iFhhSye/tdOobEqExxBebaFrFsehnXbU10/kB00lr3EVDJFCcYoJT5Sp9a7bz1r9L3CezVCrqeolUUNSN4R9qjreJCxk3YxcTnm9f//PvAIPDsqadFmZyDXcT5FyUEfiwb0cyERbL90=;
X-YMail-OSG: ivy79oIVM1k8kPIPgi4nfJh2JPdWcnzc7If0UmOfBQtmnkB
nEmfLnPHJ
Received: from [187.41.82.250] by web162602.mail.bf1.yahoo.com via HTTP; Thu, 14 Jun 2012 15:42:07 PDT
X-Mailer: YahooMailWebService/0.8.118.349524
Message-ID: <1339713727.16968.BPMail_high_noncarrier@web162602.mail.bf1.yahoo.com>
Date: Thu, 14 Jun 2012 15:42:07 -0700 (PDT)
From: Tim <tim@yahoo.com>
Subject: HI
To: bankofamerica@replies.em.bankofamerica.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can have a virus. The one that sends e-mails. If you have at least one spam e-mail try to track computers that had received it in Received header. If it tracks down to your computer - you are vulnerable.
2. They can just use your e-mail when sending spam. Nothing you can do unless your mail provider (Yahoo) would use something like DKIM or SPF.

Comment: Thanks! (1) My OS is Ubuntu. I think it is very unlikely to have virus? How can I know if it has? (2) The sent spams can be seen in my "Sent" folder, and does that mean that the spams are actually sent from my account?

Comment: Can you show headers at least for one suck e-mail?

Comment: See my update to my original post. Thanks!

Comment: Look at the Received line for IP address. Is this your address or are you related to it?

Comment: You meant "187.41.82.250"? It is from a different country. Does that mean my original password was not compromised, and my account hasn't been accessed by a different person?

Comment: I guess no, as web162602.mail.bf1.yahoo.com accepted this message. I think you can be compromised.

Comment: (1) I still wonder how I can be compromised? (2) what does "web162602.mail.bf1.yahoo.com accepted this message“ imply? (3) Would you point me to some tutorials that analyze various ways that spams can use my email address? （4） I also update with the header of a spam sent from my address to another email account and cc to my address itself. Thanks!

Comment: (1) Someone guessed your password or obtained it from other sources. (2) By hostname I can assume this is some yahoo web gateway. As there is no other untrusted Received entries this one can be trusted as this the host that transferred your mail into storage. (3) dunno any (4) And that's strange. The same host appears in your real message. This can mean this is something inside yahoo network or part of your headers from spam message disappeared. This maybe a good time to show both to yahoo support  as maybe they would be able to sched some light at first mail source.

Comment: （1） In your post, by "If you have at least one spam e-mail try to track computers that had received it in Received header". do you mean that I open a received spam and click a link in it, so the spammer get confirm that my computer has received its spam? How can they take advantage of that to guess my password and to send emails from my account? (2) I have updated the second example so that it corresponds to the first example. The original second example does not correspond to the first example.

Comment: (1) No, I mean that every computer in receive chain takes responsibility on retransmitting message. If all this computers belongs to Yahoo maube you should ask them about this accident. (2) This is just a notice that such e-mail account doesn't exist which was mailed to you by yahoo, this is not the spam e-mail itself. This is quite common that spam message is sent to nonexistent account, real sender are listed in BCC: field.

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu you can add a good firewall. That will be the complete protection that a linux user can have. One of the firewall that I would recommend is firestarter for linux and avast anti-virus for windows. Avast is a free and very good anti-virus

Comment: Thanks! What can a firewall do for my computer?

Comment: It can monitor the incoming and outgoing connection in your computer so that data is not transmitted from suspicious IP addresses. In short it guarantees you that no insecure connection will be made and no chance of virus from internet.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the original email was sent with false headers. As the target is Bank of America it could also be part of a DDOS attack on them.